# Google web fonts blurry in firefox

Tags: html, text, fonts

I'm using google web fonts for a project, and have had no issues so far.  I have a text shadow applied to some areas, and was pretty happy with the result in Chrome.  I switched over to FF and the text was dizzyingly blurry.  This applied to all text, shadow or not.

Is this a google web font issue, or something else?

[image: chrome font]
Here's a screenshot of chrome

[image: ff font]
...and FF

Comment: What version of FF and what OS?

Comment: @j08691 The latest of both on Mac Snow Leopard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also having many issues with this at the moment...

You can try adding `font-weight:normal;` or `font-weight:100;` to your CSS, but I have found this work only sometimes.

My fonts all work correctly on FF (even IE) on PC, but using FF on MacOSX (Snow Leopard) they give that bold/blurry effect :(

Comment: Changing the font weight from bold, and bolder to normal did fix the blurriness, but now the font is thinner than I'd prefer.  Looks like I'll need a bolder font to begin with.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Try toggling the hardware acceleration in options/preferences > advanced.

Read somewhere that rendering of fonts changed with increasing usage of hardware acceleration.

Also you can try tweaking at OS level. Go to system preferences > Appearances > Font-smoothing  and tweak options there. Many people find blurry font issues because of mac's font-smoothing technique.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

I had to include this property: `font-synthesis: none` to suppress browser's enhancement on the fonts.

[Read more on this property here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-synthesis)